# SQL select where month/year are within 2 dates

Tags: sql, select

I have the following table:

| id | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/03/2021 | 24/09/2022 |
| 2 | 11/06/2021 | 19/12/2022 |
| 3 | 17/09/2021 | 22/03/2022 |
| 4 | 21/05/2021 | 30/05/2022 |

and I have 2 inputs, month and year, what I need is to get the dates where the selected month/year is within the start and end date, for example, the input is 07/2022, the results I need are:

| id | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/03/2021 | 24/09/2022 |
| 2 | 11/06/2021 | 19/12/2022 |

what I tried:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  contracts 
where 
    (year(startdate) >= @year 
    and 
    month(startdate) >=@month)  
  and 
    (year(enddate) <= @year 
    and
    month(enddate) <=@month)
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: just updated my question, added the query that I've tried

Comment: What should be returned if month 6 is entered, instead of month 7?

Comment: the results would be the same 1 and 2 when you use month 6, but if you use month 4 , it will return id 1,2 , and 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ClumZZZey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8731800/clumzzzey)'s approach is correct. Seems like there is a small mistake on the query. Try this instead.

```
SELECT * 
FROM contracts
WHERE (year(startdate) * 100 + month(startdate)) <= @year * 100 + @month 
  AND (year(enddate) * 100 +  month(enddate)) >= @year * 100 + @month
```

Comment: thaaaaaanks, worked as I want, thank you, i didn't pay attention to that small mistake on ClumZZZey's answer.

Comment: You're welcome! Very glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Decoupling the month and the year makes it tricky. You want to keep the together.
For example

```
SELECT * 
FROM contracts
WHERE (year(startdate) * 100 + month(startdate)) <= @year * 100 + @month 
AND (year(enddate) * 100 +  month(enddate)) >= @year * 100 + @month
```

EDIT: switched the < and > to the correct places.

Comment: unfortunately, no results with ur answer!